# Count rows from two tables associateds to a third table

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables: data, network and software. The data table has all my client's names while the network and software tables has service tickets. We need a minimum of one ticket per client per month from any of both tables (network or software).  I need a query to count tickets from both tables (network and software) for each client in the data table for each month.

[my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfdBg.jpg)

Desire result:
[Final query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMv2G.jpg)

I found the way to count with this query but I don’t know how to count from both tables.

```
SELECT institucion
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2016-07%')as July
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2016-08%')as August
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2016-09%')as September
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2016-10%')as October
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2016-11%')as November
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2016-12%')as December
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2017-01%')as January
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2017-02%')as February
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2017-03%')as March
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2017-04%')as April
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2017-05%')as May
    ,(SELECT count(institucion) FROM network WHERE data.institucion = network.institucion and fecha like '2017-06%')as June
FROM data
where data.erate = 'y'
order by institucion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to `UNION` together the `network` and `software` tables, and then use conditional aggregation to get count summaries for each of the months of interest.

```
SELECT t1.institucion,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2016-07%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS July,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2016-08%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS August,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2016-09%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS September,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2016-10%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS October,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2016-11%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS November,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2016-12%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS December,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2017-01%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS January,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2017-02%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS February,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2017-03%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS March,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2017-04%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS April,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2017-05%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.fetcha LIKE '2017-06%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS June
FROM
(
    SELECT institucion, fecha, service
    FROM network n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT institucion, fecha, service
    FROM software s
) t1
INNER JOIN data t2
    ON t1.institucion = t2.institucion
WHERE t2.erate = 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agreen with Tim, Also you can try Pivot

For example:

```
     SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT institucion
                ,LEFT(fecha,7) AS [month],COUNT(institucion) AS cnt
            FROM DATA AS d
            LEFT JOIN network AS n ON d.institucion=n.institucion
            where data.erate = 'y'
            GROUP BY institucion,LEFT(fecha,7)
     ) AS t
    PIVOT(MAX(cnt) FOR [month] IN ([2016-07],[2016-08],[2016-09],[2016-10],[2016-11],[2016-12],[2017-01],[2017-02],[2017-03],[2017-04],[2017-05],[2017-06])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply **Dynamic pivot** on computed result set of Software And Network tables.

Lets build schema of your Images

```
CREATE TABLE #DATA (INSTITUTION VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #DATA
SELECT 'CLIENT1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT4'


CREATE TABLE #NETWORK (INSTITUTION VARCHAR(20), FECHA DATE, SERVICE VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #NETWORK

SELECT 'CLIENT2', '2016-11-20', 'internet confirmation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT3', '2016-11-07', 'internet confirmation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT1', '2016-12-02', 'internet confirmation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT2', '2016-10-31', 'internet confirmation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT3', '2016-10-20', 'internet confirmation'


CREATE TABLE #SOFTWARE (INSTITUTION VARCHAR(20), FECHA DATE, SERVICE VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #SOFTWARE

SELECT 'CLIENT4', '2016-12-04', 'installation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT2', '2016-11-25', 'configuration'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT1', '2016-11-02', 'installation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT3', '2016-10-31', 'installation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLIENT3', '2016-10-20', 'configuration'
```

Now Query the Data and Store(`INSERT`) in a Temp Table(`#PIVOTING`) for to build dynamic Query.

```
SELECT D.INSTITUTION, COMB.MONTH_NAME, COUNT(1) AS TICKET_COUNT 
INTO #PIVOTING  --Taking Data in Temp table 
FROM #DATA D
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT INSTITUTION, FECHA, [SERVICE], DATENAME(YY,FECHA)+'-'+ DATENAME(MM, FECHA) MONTH_NAME
    FROM #NETWORK

    UNION ALL

 SELECT INSTITUTION, FECHA, [SERVICE],DATENAME(YY,FECHA)+'-'+ DATENAME(MM, FECHA) MONTH_NAME
    FROM #SOFTWARE
) AS COMB ON D.INSTITUTION = COMB.INSTITUTION
GROUP BY D.INSTITUTION, COMB.MONTH_NAME
```

Now pick column names into a variable for Pivot and use them in dynamic query of pivot

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX) =(
        SELECT STUFF((
                    SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + MONTH_NAME + ']'
                    FROM #PIVOTING
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')
        )

DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(MAX) ='
        SELECT * FROM #PIVOTING AS DATA
        PIVOT (MAX(TICKET_COUNT) FOR MONTH_NAME IN ( ' + @COLUMNS +') 

            ) PVT


'

EXEC( @QRY)
```